# Copying large data from Interbase to text file by using Pentaho Spoon

Tags: copy, pentaho, interbase, spoon

Do you have any idea for copying large data from interbase to text file by using Pentaho Spoon.

I knew the simple process just use table input and then text file output.Please see the picture.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0lAU.png)

However, I am concern about if the data is large, I think this step may be take time. Any idea for this issue? I am trying to find some solution may be there are some cmd command to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major bottlenecks will be the speed at which Interbase returns data and the network. Spoon won’t be a major hurdle. If you see it running slowly you may want to install and run locally, in the same host as interbase and at least it won’t have network speed to deal with.

But in the end, if the query is slow there’s not mucj you can do from PDI side.

To run from the command line you can use pan.sh/pan.bat to run transformations or kitchen.sh/kitchen.bat to run jobs.

Comment: Thanks for your help